# how to block a request from other domains in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes, cross-domain

I am new to node js, got one task to do. I have below code. I need to block requests from other domains except couple of which are allowed. Could you please help me how to perform this task.

```js
import express from 'express';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import cors from 'cors';
import requestIp from 'request-ip';
import os from 'os';
import { AppRoutes, AuthRoutes } from './routes';
import { logger } from './shared-services/logger';
import { MESSAGE } from './constants/index';

const app = express();

app.use(cors());
app.disable('x-powered-by');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use((req, res, next)=> {
  const clientIp = requestIp.getClientIp(req);
  logger.debug(JSON.stringify(req.socket.address()));
  logger.debug(`incoming IP ${clientIp}`);
  next();
});

//api Routes.

app.use('/abc', AuthRoutes);

// Check if route exist
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  if (!req.route) {
    logger.error(`${req.originalUrl}, ${MESSAGE.ERROR_NO_ENDPOINT}`);
    res.status(404).send(returnResponseObj(`${req.originalUrl}, ${MESSAGE.ERROR_NO_ENDPOINT}`));
  }
  next();
});

export default app;
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use CORS(Cross Orgin Request) to block or add other domains.

this is the npm link

[cors npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors)

```
var express = require('express')
var cors = require('cors')
var app = express()

var whitelist = ['http://example1.com', 'http://example2.com']
var corsOptions = {
  origin: function (origin, callback) {
    if (whitelist.indexOf(origin) !== -1) {
      callback(null, true)
    } else {
      callback(new Error('Not allowed by CORS'))
    }
 }
}

 app.get('/products/:id', cors(corsOptions), function (req, res, next) {
   res.json({msg: 'This is CORS-enabled for a whitelisted domain.'})
 })
```

Comment: could you please help me with simple example so that I can understand easily. Thanks for reply.

Comment: I edited with code sample. it will only allow the white listed urls, you can dynamicaly add urls to the whitelist array. if you want ot block some specific urls to block (all other will be allowed ) you need to change your "if" statement.

Comment: I have such two URLs to be allowed and rest should be blocked.                              test - https://<servername>.test.abc.com                                            
 prod - https://<servername>.internal.abc.com   . How can I use these two in my existing code.  What if I just comment a app.use(cors()); line.

Comment: app.get('/products/:id', cors(corsOptions), function (req, res, next) {
   res.json({msg: 'This is CORS-enabled for a whitelisted domain.'})
 }).       //   Check this line.